# for loop in a for loop without duplicating the output

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically referencing data from an api callback but i am stuck with getting a set of data to loop and display the results properly.

Here is a screenshot of how it should look like

[image]

Its hard to explain it but basically everything you see is dynamically referenced including the clickable links and they are generated by going through a loop.

My problem is the callback string from the api has multiple objects and i need to extract all the objects from it and display it within set shown below which are also dynamically generated.

Anyhow, if there is a solution to this i will try apply it to the real code.

-- HERE IS MY REAL CODE --

```
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.endpoints.length; i++) {
                var endpoint1 = response.endpoints[i];

                $response0.append('<div class="EndPoint"><a href="#"><h3>Endpoint ['+i+']</h3></a><div><h3>Protocols</h3>'+protocols.name+' '+protocols.version+'</div></div>');            
                }
                $('.EndPoint').on('click', function () {
                $('.EndPoint').find('div').hide();
                $(this).find('div').show();
                });
```

I need to somehow factor in this code as part of the loop. I can't display it in jsfiddle because the string comes from an api but it works seperately:

```
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < endpoint1.details.protocols.length; ii++) {
                var protocols = endpoint1.details.protocols[ii];
                console.log(protocols);
                }
```

I have included in a image of what the call back string data looks like in firebug.. i am only interested in the name and version values

[image]

Comment: post the relevant code here as well, please

Comment: It's still difficult to figure out how should `['a','b','c']` be sorted into the different sets. Does it mean every set has a unique array that it should display?

Comment: Why are you creating the `set [n]` nodes at the letter level? Create that node at the number level, append to it in the letter level. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wfLkmpxx/4/

Comment: Tweaks: https://jsfiddle.net/wfLkmpxx/7

Comment: sorry guys, i have posted the real code to give you guys more context. I am very sorry if i am not articulating the issue properly.

Comment: So, what's your real problem? Do you want to loop through all protocols inside each endpoint? All answers to your question provide a solution for that...

Comment: correct. i am trying one of the solutions and i have the protocol data getting updated in all the right places now but the click function to show/hide is not working.. i could use a second pair if of eyes https://jsfiddle.net/hd6bwd4o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add the link in the outer loop, and add only one item in each iteration in the inner loop, using `set2[ii]` to get the right letter:

```
var set1 = [1, 2, 3];
var set2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
    var set = $('<div class="set"><a href="#">set [' + set1[i] + ']</a></div>');
    $('#container').append(set);
    for (var ii = 0; ii < set2.length; ii++) {
        set.append('<div><b>letter:</b> ' + set2[ii] + '</div>');
    }
}

$('.set').on('click', function () {
    $('.set').find('div').hide();
    $(this).find('div').show();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/wfLkmpxx/6/

Comment: thx very much but i realize my original post may not have been accurately described so i have posted my real code.. would love your thoughts. sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @user3436467: Use a variable to hold the element that you create in the outer loop, as in my code above. Then you can append items to it in the inner loop. Use something like `set.append('<div>' + protocols.name + ' ' + protocols.version + '</div>');` to use the values from the protocol.

Comment: following your example, the protocol details are now appearing but the click function to show/hide is a little broken. the data is showing up all expanded by default.. can you take a look ? https://jsfiddle.net/hd6bwd4o/

Comment: @user3436467: Put the element that you create in a variable, so that you can add elements to it, otherwise the inner elements will end up between the outer elements, not inside them. You should bind the click event once after the loop, otherwise the elements will have multiple click events. https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hd6bwd4o/1/

Comment: champion! it works with your code. I just had to add the <div> in the set and it works perfectly `set.append('<div>' + protocols.name + ' ' + protocols.version + '<br></div>');`

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, you will need to create your `div` element. Then, in the second loop, you need to create the list items. Outside of the second loop, but still inside the first loop, you need to append these list items to the `div` element just defined within the first loop.

I tried to make the logic clear: https://jsfiddle.net/wfLkmpxx/8/

```
var set1=[1,2,3];
var set2=['a','b','c'];

for(var i=0;i<set1.length; i++){

    var div1 = $('<div class="set"><a href="#">set ['
        + set1[i] 
        + ']</a><div>');
    var sublinks ='';

    for(var ii=0;ii<set2.length; ii++){       
        sublinks +=  '<div><b>letter:</b> ' + set2[ii] + '</div>';        
    }

    div1.append(sublinks);
    $('#container').append(div1);
}


$('.set').on('click', function () {
    $('.set').find('div').hide();
    $(this).find('div').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems in your `for` loops. You have to create a new jQuery element for each set in the first loop (before the second loop) and append each letter to this element in the second loop.

```
var set1=[1,2,3],
    set2=['a','b','c'],
    $container =  $('#container'),
    $tempSet,
    $tempSetChilds;

for(var i=0;i<set1.length; i++){
    $tempSet = $('<div class="set"><a href="#">set ['+set1[i]+']</a><div></div>');
    $tempSetChilds = $tempSet.children('div');

    $container.append($tempSet);

    for(var ii=0;ii<set2.length; ii++){
        $tempSetChilds.append('<b>letter:</b> ' +set2[ii]+ '<br>');
    }
}

$('.set').on('click', function () {
    $('.set').find('div').hide();
    $(this).find('div').show();
});
```

Check it out in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wfLkmpxx/1/

Comment: thx very much but i realize my original post may not have been accurately described so i have posted my real code.. would love your thoughts. sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your JS to the following:

```
var set1=[1,2,3];
var set2=['a','b','c'];
for(var i=0; i<set1.length; i++){
    $('#container').append('<div class="set" id=' + i + '><a href="#">set [' + set1[i] + ']</a></div>');
    for(var ii=0; ii<set2.length; ii++){
        $('#' + i).append('<div><b>letter:</b> ' + set2[ii] + '</div>');
    }

    $('.set').on('click', function () {
        $('.set').find('div').hide();
        $(this).find('div').show();
    });
}
```

In addition to making it work, I made the code look properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution out, hope it helps:

```
var set1=[1,2,3];
var set2=['a','b','c'];
for(var i=0;i<set1.length; i++){
$('#container').append('<div class="set" id='+i+'><a href="#">set ['+set1[i]+']</a>');
for(var ii=0;ii<set2.length; ii++){
$('#'+i).append('<div><b>letter:</b> '+set2[ii]+ '<br></div></div>');
}


$('.set').on('click', function () {
$('.set').find('div').hide();
$(this).find('div').show();
});
}
```

you can [find it on  jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfLkmpxx/9/)

Comment: thx very much but i realize my original post may not have been accurately described so i have posted my real code.. would love your thoughts. sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You have put everything in one loop. Separate the appends!

Here's a working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sshLuf41/)

```
var set1 = [1, 2, 3];
var set2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var i = 0; i < set1.length; i++) {
    $('#container').append('<div class="set" id="set' + set1[i] + '"><a href="#">set [' + set1[i] + ']</a><div id="letterwrap">');
    for (var ii = 0; ii < set2.length; ii++) {
        if (ii != 0) {
            $('#set'+set1[i]).find('#letterwrap').append('<br/>');
        }
        $('#set'+set1[i]).find('#letterwrap').append('<b> letter: </b> ' + set2[ii]);
    }
    $('#container').append('</div></div>');

    $('.set').on('click', function () {
        $('.set').find('#letterwrap').hide();
        $(this).find('#letterwrap').show();
    });
}
```

Comment: thx very much but i realize my original post may not have been accurately described so i have posted my real code.. would love your thoughts. sorry for the trouble!